# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator

Tags: java, axiom

I am getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator.
```

i have included `axiom-api-1.2.7.jar` also, but still i am getting the exception.can any one tell me, how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the scenario you have?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the jar had a manifest.mf file inside it which defined the classpath. I guess this takes priority over any env variable of the -classpath option in the java command in command prompt.

This is my manifest.mf file after changes

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: 1.6.0_20-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: Arcot
Main-Class: com.arcot.csso.credchangereportsvc.CredChangeReportSVC
Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/classes lib/TPFService-XBeans-packaged.jar lib/TPFServ ice-client.jar lib/aspectjrt.jar lib/axis2-kernel-1.4.1.jar lib/commo ns-lang-2.5.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/ojdbc14-10.2.0.1.0.jar lib/x mlbeans-2.4.0.jar ./conf/ lib/axiom-api-1.2.7.jar lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar lib/XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar lib/axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar lib/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar lib/neethi-2.0.4.jar lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
```

Comment: You wrote an answer, not a comment. And even a `comment` allows for **some** formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator` is not in your classpath, that is, the `axiom-api-1.2.7.jar` you added doesn't contain that class.

In fact if you look [apache-axiom-api-1.2.7.jar content](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapacheaxiomapi127jar.htm) there's no org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator class.

This class seems to be present in `apache-axiom-api-1.2.9.jar`, so from 1.2.9 version on.